# Vim - plugin youcompleteme install problem

Tags: vim

I'm using [Ubuntu 16.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_.28Xenial_Xerus.29) (Xenial Xerus), and I try to install the *youcompleteme* plugin of Vim, but it shows this log error. How can I fix it?

> "YouCompleteMe unavailable: invalid syntax (vimsupport.py, line 184) "

Answer (score 2):

[Line 184 of `ycm/Vim support.py`](https://github.com/ycm-core/YouCompleteMe/blob/fa8c985dee864d33e48e3b3e803b541bdc433ffa/python/ycm/vimsupport.py#L184) in YouCompleteMe uses an [f-string](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings), which is a feature introduced only on Python 3.6.

So you need Python 3.6 or newer for YouCompleteMe to work.

Ubuntu 16.04 is over 4.5 years old and there are two LTS versions of the OS available at this point. You should strongly consider upgrading to a more recent version of Ubuntu, not just for a newer Python version, but also Vim and everything else.